# Intuitive computation of localizations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, intuition, localization

I am taking a class in algebraic geometry, where one of the needed basic skills is to be able to compute localizations. Since this computation is usually skipped in our lecture, I have the feeling that we should be able to do this "by intuition", but most often I am unable to do that.

In here, let's restrict ourselves to **localizations of rings** (commutative and with $1$) at some multiplicative set. So let $A$ be a ring and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset (containing $1$), and denote the localization of $A$ at $S$ by $S^{-1}A$. Then my first question is:

**1. What is the strategy (in general) to determine the localization $S^{-1}A$, not by raw computation but rather by intuition or by expectations on "how it should look like"?**

From my understanding, $S^{-1}A$ should be something like a smallest "ring extension" of $A$ such that all elements of $S$ become invertible, so basically one introduces something like fractions. In some cases, this is enough for me to intuitively see the result. One important case (for algebraic geometry) are **polynomial rings**. For instance, let $k$ be a field and $A=k[T]$ the polynomial ring in one variable, and let $S=\{T^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$, then we get
$$k[T]_T:=S^{-1}A=k[T,T^{-1}],$$
since the elements can be seen as fractions $f/(T^n)$ and one can see that this will lead to any rational function. In general, since we basically deal with fractions, my next question is:

**2. If we localize $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ at some multiplicative subset, do we always get something which is isomorphic to a subset of $k[T_1,T_1^{-1},\dots,T_n,T_n^{-1}]$?**

My last question will be something more specific from algebraic geometry.

**3. Let $X=Spec(k[T_1,T_2])$ (as a scheme) and let $U=X\setminus \{(T_1,T_2)\}$. Show that $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$ which is not affine.**

It is clear that $U=X\setminus V(\{T_1,T_2\})$ is open in $X$. Assume that $U=Spec(A)$ was affine. My idea is to somehow show how $A$ must look like in this case and lead this to a contradiction. We have
$$A=\Gamma(Spec(A),\mathcal{O}_{Spec(A)})\cong \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X\mid_U)=\mathcal{O}_X\mid_U(U) = \varprojlim_{D(f)\subseteq U} k[T_1,T_2]_f=\varprojlim_{f\notin k} k[T_1,T_2]_f.$$
(I hope the notations are clear). Now here I was stuck, because I was unable to compute this. I was told that this should be simply $k$, but I do not see why, I am just lacking of that intuition I guess, which is why I opened this topic. If $A=k$ is true, then it follows that $U=Spec(k)=0$ contradicting $U=X\setminus\{(T_1,T_2)\}$. This proof by contradiction is the usual strategy to show that something is not affine, I believe.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a lot to say here.

1) I'm not sure how to answer this question. Just allow yourself to invert things in $S$. $S\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}\inv A$ is just $A$ where you allow yourself to divide by things in $S$, or fractions with numerators in $A$ and denominators in $S$. Not sure what you're looking for exactly here.

2) No. Note that $k(T)\ne k[T,T\inv]$. $\frac{1}{T+1}\not\in k[T,T\inv]$.

3) Note that $\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec k[x,y]$ is an integral scheme. Hence it has a well-defined field of rational functions, $k(x,y)$. An element of $\newcommand{\calO}{\mathcal{O}}\calO(U)$ is a collection of pairs $(f_i/g_i,D(g_i))$ of rational functions that agree on their overlaps, i.e. such that $f_i/g_i=f_j/g_j$ on $D(g_i)\cap D(g_j)$.
I.e. as an element of the field of rational functions, $f_i/g_i$ is well defined, call it $F$. Now because $k[x,y]$ is a UFD, there is a unique 
smallest denominator $g$ such that $Fg = f\in k[x,y]$. Hence $D(g_i)\subset D(g)$ for all $g_i$. Then we must have that $U\subset D(g)$, or that the zeros of $g$ are at most the origin. However, over an
algebraically closed field, no polynomial in two variables has only one maximal ideal as a zero, in fact if $g\not\in k$, then $g$ will have a zero at $(p)$ for every prime factor of $g$ anyway. Hence $g$ must have no zeroes, so $g\in k$. But then $F\in k[x,y]$. Hence $k[x,y]\subset \calO(U)\subset k[x,y]$, so $\calO(U)=k[x,y]$. But $U$ is missing a point compared to $\Spec\calO(U)$, so $U$ is not affine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! About 1): Yes, this idea (inverting elements of $S$) is the "intuition" that I meant, which is often enough to compute the localization. I was just wondering if there is some further "intuitive ideas" that I was missing, cause in our class the computation you did in 3) would usually be skipped. But maybe there just is none. About 2): Why is that a counterexample? How do we get $k(T)$ as a localization? About 3): That is less intuitive than I had hoped for, but seems correct^^ In the end you conclude $f\in k[x,y]$, I think you meant $F\in k[x,y]$, right?

Comment: Sorry I did mean $F$. I'll edit tonight when I get a chance. $k(T)$ is not a localization at a multiplicative set generated by finitely many elements. It's the localization at $k[T]\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @lattice As long as the ring is an integral domain, nothing additional needs to be thought of. But if it is not, you need to be careful: If you have inverted $a$ and you have $ab = 0$ in the original ring, then you need to get $b=0$ in the localized ring.